# Configuring Scala Dispatch to use HTTP/1.0

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I'm using Dispatch v0.11.0.  I want to use it to send HTTP/1.0 requests.

I can see that it is possible to configure a few things:

```
val dispatcher = Http.configure(_.setRequestTimeoutInMs(timeoutMs))
```

However I cannot find a way to configure the object to user HTTP/1.0, is it possible?